# Concatenate tables in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have two tables T1 and T2 in csv format. Both T1 and T2 contain certain data about ships on the North Sea. T1 contains dynamic data for several ships, i.e. the data changes over time (like position, speed and so on). T2 contains exactly one entry per ship (with length, width, ID and so on), called the static data. Both T1 and T2 have an "ID" column, which I want to exploit for concatenating the tables in a certain way: I want to append the static data columns from T2 to every entry in T1 that has the same ID. I read that astropy has some fancy table operations but couldn´t figure out a way to do this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: idea: `module csv`, read into dictionary with key = Id and values = list of your static data. read into 2nd dictionary with key = Id and values = list of your dynamic data.  dict_static[key].extend(dict_dynamic[key]) for all keys. Make sure that: all data from static is wellformed (same amount), all data from dynamic is well formed (same amount), any dynamic has a static ID counterpart and any static but non dynamic ship is filled up csv-column wise.

Comment: Good luck with your coding. If you happen to get a solution you could post it as answer to this non-question. If you have a specific problem, consider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and your exception / expectation that do not get met by your code and I am sure SO will help you out. Coding your Specs does not fit into SO Q&A format - sorry.